# Date in LWC - Year field shows extra values

Tags: lightning-web-components, datetime, date

When the user selects a year for Date, an alphanumeric value appears next to the year. Does anyone know how to remove this extra alphanumeric value? any help is greatly appreciated!

This is a custom LWC Code

```
 <lightning-input label="Date of Birth" type="date" > </lightning-input>
```

[image]

Comment: What's the context for this? A standard dropdown, custom LWC, etc? Do you have any code you can share?

Comment: @sfdcfox This is a custom LWC  
<lightning-input label="Date of Birth" type="date" > </lightning-input>

Comment: Hi @ManvirBhatti, we are seeing the same behavior. Do you know if this is a Salesforce known issue? Was there any solution to this that you have found?

Answer (score 2):

I found this in the source code. Japan has its own calendar year, which is what these parenthesized strings mean.

```
getYearDisplayValue(date, yearValue) {
    date.setFullYear(yearValue);

    let displayValue = toLocalizedDigits(
        String(toOtherCalendar(date).getFullYear())
    );

    // additional display value for Japanese calendar year support
    if (showJapaneseCalendar) {
        let jpYear = this.getJapaneseCalendarYear(yearValue);
        if (jpYear) {
            displayValue += ' (' + jpYear + ')';
        }
    }
    return displayValue;
}
```

As far as I can tell, there's no way to hide this; it will either be a short form (as it appears in your dropdown) if your language is not Japanese, or the long version if your language is set to Japanese.

If you really don't want this, you can make your own custom date picker using the source code found in [lightning-base-components](https://www.npmjs.com/package/lightning-base-components).

Comment: We are seeing the same behavior @sfdcfox and looking into it. There should be a workaround as forced default just doesn't feel right as going this route Salesforce will force a UX behavior on all their users where it kind of helps only a subset of users; seems like solving for an exception.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to sfdcfox for figuring out that this was related to the Japanese Imperial calendar ([article on the functionality](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.enable_japanese_imperial_calendar.htm&type=5)).

This is a [known issue](https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p4V000001wCxEQAU&title=japanese-imperial-calendar-showing-in-byo-template) with Communities (Experiences) recognised by Salesforce and scheduled to be fixed in the Winter 23 release.

For now I suggest letting Salesforce know if you're affected and raising a case with their support team to see if there's anything they can do to help (unless you want to use the workarounds suggested by sfdcfox or in the Known Issue).

[image]